# jQuery addClass to every item that have x children?

Tags: jquery, size, each, children, addclass

I want to add class "anything" to every item that has more than 2 children.
Unfortunately my code doesn't work, I guess I have to define (this) and maybe use each, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Here's my code:

```
if ( jQuery('#container .document').children().size() > 2 ) {
     jQuery(this).addClass("anything"); 
}
```

An broken example:

http://jsfiddle.net/HHSuM/1/

Comment: A few minor things: (1) `$( '.document', '#container' )` is more efficient. (2) You don't have to use `jQuery` instead of `$` if your jQuery code is inside the ready handler (where it should be anyway), since you can pass in the `$` name into this handler: `jQuery(function ($) { ... your code ... });`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop over the elements with `.each()`:

```
$('#container .document').each(function() {
  if (this.children.length > 2) {
    $(this).addClass('anything');
  }
});
```

Comment: You could also test `($(this).children(:gt(1)).length)`, but I suspect that using `>` instead of `:gt` is faster.

Comment: Thank you, I have an additional question, if I have about 50 .document elements on my page and they have around 50-100 children - will this code slow my site down a lot?

Comment: Nope. You'll only loop over the 50 `.document`s and count the children, which shouldn't take much more than a fraction of a second. Have you tried running the code yet?

Comment: @Blender Should be `children()` (with parens). Either `$(this).children().length` or `this.children.length`.

Comment: @Blender, yes, it works like a charm, at least on localhost. Thank you a lot! :)

Answer (score 7):

You can use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter) to restrict the list to elements with more than two children.

```
jQuery('#container .document').filter(function() {
    return this.children.length > 2; //Use just the regular DOM children property in here
}).addClass("anything");
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HHSuM/4/

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about `childElementCount`. `:)`

Answer (score 2):

I thought this was an interesting one, and tried to use `:has()` in conjunction with `:nth-child()` but I get a syntax error.

```
// Does NOT work... why?
jQuery('#container .document:has(*:nth-child(3))').addClass('anything');
```

But modifying the approach slightly, works:

```
// Nifty!
jQuery('#container .document *:nth-child(3)').parents('.document').addClass('anything');
```

Basically we're looking for elements with a 3rd element, then moving up the DOM.

Comment: got to give it to you, it is indeed a nifty selector, though for simplicity, i would still use the `.filter()`,  certainly a great find though

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate through the `#container .document` elements.

Updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HHSuM/2/). Seems to work!

Answer (score 1):

you have many options here

1. you can use .each() to iterate over the items, check in the callback function whether they have 2 children or more and then add the class
2. another option i like better, is using the .filter() like this:

   ```
   $('#container .document').filter(function(){  
       return $(this).children().length > 2;
   }).addClass('anything');
   ```

   or your example: http://jsfiddle.net/saelfaer/HHSuM/6/